# Send data from detail view controller to table view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I create an app which uses https://newsapi.org/.

There is a table view that contains news and they have their detail page (Detail View Controller).

Detail view controller has a tab bar button item which is favorites button(<3).

This button send data to favorites table view. But can't send data. Also, in favorites table view you can click the cell and go detail view controller again. So there is two way. And i want to go BACK segue.

main.storyboard: [image]

this is NewsTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController , UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    var arr : [Article]? = []
    var filteredData: [Article] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        //
        //        let parameters = ["q":"%20", "page": "1", "apiKey":"06c2318ea4c64504b48b3d126168203c"]
        
        
        let parameters = ["q":"saliha", "page": "1", "apiKey":"06c2318ea4c64504b48b3d126168203c"]
        
        let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything"
        
        
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters) .responseJSON { (res) in
            
            if(res.response?.statusCode == 200) {
                
                print("res data: ",res.data as Any)
                
                let news = try? JSONDecoder().decode(News.self, from: res.data!)
                self.arr = news?.articles
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
                
                
                
                print("kaç sonuç var?",news?.totalResults as Any)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if(filteredData.count > 0) {
            return filteredData.count
        } else {
            return arr!.count
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
        let item: Article
        if filteredData.count > 0 {
            item = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            item = arr![indexPath.row]
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let url = URL(string: item.urlToImage!)
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
            cell.newsImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            
        }
        
        cell.newsTitle.text = item.title
        cell.newsAbout.text = item.description
        
        
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let sender: Article
        if filteredData.count > 0 {
            sender = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
            sender = arr![indexPath.row]
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: sender)
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if ( segue.identifier == "detail" ) {
            let vc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            vc.item = (sender as! Article)
        }
        
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = []
        if searchText == ""{
            filteredData = arr!
        }
        else{
            for item in arr!{
                if item.title!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()){
                    filteredData.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }

}
```

this is DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var item: Article!
    
    var arr: [Article] = []
    
    var favArr: [Article] = []
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dDate: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dAbout: UITextView!
    
    @IBAction func btnWebview(_ sender: Any) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goWeb", sender: item)
        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnFav(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        print("favoriler ekleme butonuna basıldı")
        
    
        
               
            
            
        }

    
    
    
    @IBAction func btnShare(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        let items = [URL(string: item.url!)]
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items as [Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(ac, animated: true)
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let url = URL(string: item.urlToImage!)
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        dImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        
        dTitle.text = item.title
        dAbout.text = item.description
        dDate.text = item.publishedAt
      
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if ( segue.identifier == "goWeb" ) {
            let vc = segue.destination as! WebViewViewController
            vc.item = (sender as! Article)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

this is FavoriteTableViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class FavoriteTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var item: Article!
    var arr : [Article]? = []
    var favArr: [Article] = []
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return favArr.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "favcell", for: indexPath) as! FavoriteTableViewCell

        
    
        let url = URL(string: item.urlToImage!)
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!)
        cell.fImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
        cell.fTitle.text = item.title
        cell.fDetail.text = item.description
        
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: item)
        
    }
    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: you want to go backwards to the favorite view controller by pressing the heart?

Comment: by pressing the heart, I want the news to be added to the favorite table